# What is meant by interleaved "multi-threading" in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Can anybody explain what is an interleaved multi-threading means? 
Real-time examples are also allowed.

Comment: None of the answer distinguishes interleaved multi-threading from SMT.

Answer (score 1):

This is described by Intel as hyper-threading.  The CPU has a single core with 2 register sets.

These can be used to increase the utilisation of the core.

This is opaque to code, in that it behaves like 2 cores.  However only one at a time can run.

If multi-threaded, your code still needs atomic, mutexes etc

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)#Interleaved_multithreading) says:

> The purpose of interleaved multithreading is to remove all data
>   dependency stalls from the execution pipeline. Since one thread is
>   relatively independent from other threads, there's less chance of one
>   instruction in one pipe stage needing an output from an older
>   instruction in the pipeline. Conceptually, it is similar to preemptive
>   multitasking used in operating systems; an analogy would be that the
>   time slice given to each active thread is one CPU cycle.

Answer (score 0):

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29#Interleaved_multithreading) explains it pretty well.

Basically it's about interleaving instructions from different OS-level threads on the CPU, to reduce the risk of costly dependencies between instructions.